# Individualized heart beat data linked with heart disease

Tags: data-request, medical

Do you know of any open data set recording individualized heart beat time series as well as occurrences of heart diseases?

I am thinking of something like a database from health monitoring wrist bands coupled with an indication of whether and when the person wearing the band was affected by some common heart diseases.

If none are available, I would still be interested in any individualized data from health monitoring wrist bands linked to some record of medical conditions.

Comment: Disclaimer : I realize that there are already a couple of related questions on the site, but from what I've seen, this one seemed specific enough to justify a new question. Feel free to mark as duplicate if you feel it's appropriate.